# Can I reset the Kindle Fire HD and power off without going to setup?

Tags: factory-reset, amazon-kindle-fire-hd

I just got a Kindle Fire HD which Im planning to give away as a gift to a friend. But I need to boot it and write a review on my website before giving it. So, how can I make it look like I never switched it on?

When we boot the tablet, it'll give us a setup wizard. After resetting, we will get to the setup wizard again. My question is, how to power off the tablet without following the setup and will it show the setup when I power it again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the setup, you may be able to bypass it. This is the case if it is the default Google setup wizard.

If it is not, then there may be no way to bypass it, and you will therefore have to follow it through.

When you wipe the device, it will show again on next boot, so why don't you just follow the setup and then wipe it? This way it will be as if it was never booted for the next person to turn it on.

Comment: If I wipe it again, it will reboot and go to the setup again :)

Comment: Use it then wipe it.